# If I create my own distro, how would I change text displayed when booting (eg "ubuntu 13.04")?

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to make my own distro. I have made quite some progress, but I'm now stuck at changing the text displayed while the system is booting.

When my customized Ubuntu mini remix is booting and it is on the reddish screen with a progress bar, Ubuntu 13.04 is displayed above the progress bar (those few dots changing colors).

How can I change this?

I have tried in many ways. ubuntu-builder didn't change it and even editing some configuration files didn't give me any results.

Comment: I don't use 13.04, but in 12.04, I believe `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth` is responsible for that text. Search for something symilar, and adit it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't worked :(

Answer (score -1):

`/etc/lsb-release` is what you are looking for.